# Ruby- accessing elements multidimensional array

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

could you anyone help me with the logic to change/organize `log` entries

```
input_array = [
  ["2/6/2014", "13:31:12", "IN", "application1", "user1", "machine1"]
  ["2/6/2014", "13:31:12", "IN", "application2", "user2", "machine2"]
  ["2/6/2014", "13:31:52", "IN", "application3", "user3", "machine3"]
  ["2/6/2014", "13:38:37", "OUT", "application1", "user1", "machine1"]
  ["2/6/2014", "14:46:37", "OUT", "application2", "user2", "machine2"]
  ["2/6/2014", "15:56:37", "OUT", "application3", "user3", "machine3"]
]
```

How to access individual elements within this array .. such as `2/6/2014` or `application1`?

when I do `input_array[1][4]`, the desired output is ...

```
"application1" # and not 6 ... its giving me the 4 character in line 1
```

appreciate your help!

Comment: What is `line`? And with that spacing, your code is not valid.

Comment: Even if you made that particular syntax valid you'd still end up with a string not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you mean this:

```
input_line = [
  ["2/6/2014", "13:31:12", "IN", "application1", "user1", "machine1"],
  ["2/6/2014", "13:31:12", "IN", "application2", "user2", "machine2"],
  ["2/6/2014", "13:31:52", "IN", "application3", "user3", "machine3"],
  ["2/6/2014", "13:38:37", "OUT", "application1", "user1", "machine1"],
  ["2/6/2014", "14:46:37", "OUT", "application2", "user2", "machine2"],
  ["2/6/2014", "15:56:37", "OUT", "application3", "user3", "machine3"]]
```

?

You can then use the syntax `input_array[i][j]` without issues!

Comment: yep, you're right. got to figure out how to get the comma's after each array... thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed code has an error, if you actually defined your array like this:

```
input_array = [
    ["2/6/2014", "13:31:12", "IN", "application1", "user1", "machine1"],
      ["2/6/2014", "13:31:12", "IN", "application2", "user2", "machine2"],
      ["2/6/2014", "13:31:52", "IN", "application3", "user3", "machine3"],
      ["2/6/2014", "13:38:37", "OUT", "application1", "user1", "machine1"],
      ["2/6/2014", "14:46:37", "OUT", "application2", "user2", "machine2"],
      ["2/6/2014", "15:56:37", "OUT", "application3", "user3", "machine3"]
    ]
```

You would then be able to access your array like this:

```
2.0.0p195 :054 > input_array[0][0]
 => "2/6/2014"
```